# NSXMLDocument initWithContentsOfURL; unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, osx-snow-leopard

if i use following code my project it giving xmldoc value as nil,but if i create  some sample project it's giving xml nodes(that html file content values).My project have somany files but that not matter, even if i call in my project "applicationDidFinishLaunching" method also it's giving null.

```
 NSString *string = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"xxx" ofType:@"html"];
 id xmlDoc = [[NSXMLDocument alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:string] options:0 error:&error];
```

Comment: Post the stack trace.

Comment: Check if you have created a file named xxx.html in app bundle

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are many stuff you could check- first make sure string is not nil and corresponds to what you expect (the resource may not be there, if you write an add-on there can be confusion on which bundle is returned...). Second you should use directly the URL variant of pathForResource (URLForResource). This would avoid you to "translate" between string and URL and possibly get a problem there

Comment: I checked my string it's have it's value(path) and i seen project resource(package content) path also it contain my file, but still it giving same error and return null value.